# How to set a Google Plus photo as a contact-picture?

Tags: google-plus-photos, contact-photo

One of my *Google Plus* contacts has some great photos from a recent family reunion I was unable to attend. I would like to use a number of these as contact photos on my Android device (Galaxy Nexus GSM w/ CyanogenMod 10.0). I have the latest Google+ app.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to DO anything with the photos, whether setting them as contact photos or saving them to the device. The Google+ app likewise does not show up as an option when setting a contact photo and choosing an app to select a picture with.

**How can I set a picture from the G+ app as a contact photo?**

I would like to set the pictures on the phone rather than from my computer because that way it keeps much higher resolution versions than setting them through the gmail contacts functions.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are tons of UI differences between the Nexus and Samsung Galaxy S4. However, here's what works for the S4, in case it leads you in the right direction.

From the Google+ slide menu, go to "Photos" and tap the desired photo. Once open, tap the phone's hardware menu button, then tap "Set as..." --> "More" --> "Contact photo" and select the desired contact.

Apologies if your Nexus doesn't have the "Set as..." menu option.

Comment: Nexus doesn't have hardware menu button, but software buttons. For the menu's items, since it is the Google+ app, they will be the same across any device :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed on my 4.2 Nexus 7.  I assume there's an easier way, but these worked for me:

- Open the Google + app
- find an article whose image has the "there be photos here" icon superimposed on it -- it looks like a circle containing a square, and inside the square is a blob that is supposed to suggest a mountain range
- tap that article
- tap the photo in the background.  This opens a new window whose header is "Photos from posts".
- tap the menu button in the upper right (it looks like three tiny squares in a column ... a bit like traffic lights).
- choose "Download Image".
- Go back to the Home screen, and find the "downloads" app.  Open it.
- Find the thing you just downloaded.  Tap it.
- Now you're in the "Gallery" app; you should see the three-tiny-squares menu button in the upper-right again.  Tap that.
- Choose "Set picture as".
- Choose "Contact photo".
- Scroll through your contacts until you find the one you want, then tap it.
- Crop it, then click "OK"

Yikes!  An awful lot of steps.

Comment: This seems to work for posts that have images attached, but not pictures in albums even if you reach them through the post on their profile that shows the album was added. The menu button on album photos doesn't have a download option.

Comment: You're right; I tried again with a different post, and only saw "Report abuse" and "Send Feedback".  Perhaps some people allow their photos to be downloaded, and others don't.

Answer (score -3):

Thats just by the help of Google Contacts, you cannot do anything on your own, however you can change contact info by yourself, like Update the Photo to user or contact!

However there is a way, every your contact on Google, will be able to get their images in your contacts. But for that their must be some Email, Phone Number, Or atleast the name matching the name or other data at the Google servers!

Comment: Perhaps it's just the language barrier, but I can't see how this answers the question.